# Pass textarea values to jsp

Tags: html, jsp, textarea

I am populating a list of string from jsp to an html `<textarea>`. e.g.

`out.println("<textarea name='word_suggest' rows='10' id='word_suggest'>");
            while(it.hasNext()){
                out.println(it.next());
            }
out.println("</textarea>");`

I want the user to edit the textarea and read back the values to jsp (e.g. create another list of strings) so that I can work around with the new list. Can I do this without using the `<form>` and `<post>` action e.g work around within the same page?

Comment: What do you want to do with the list? You could just code this client-side with javascript, or issue an Ajax request to the server if you need to perform server-side operations with the list.

Comment: I need to pass the words in the <textarea> in a java-bean method so as to query the database with them. e.g. use the method 'public Vector<codes> getCodes(String word)'

Comment: Then, issue an Ajax request. Look into [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) if you're going to do this with pure js, or [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you're going to use jQuery.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example with jQuery on how the syntax goes. I am reading the jQuery.ajax(); but I am more an example guy that needs a kick-start :)

Comment: See [jQuery AJAX POST example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5004233/851811).

Comment: The example is nice but it uses a form and a POST. How can I manage the html tags e.g. the textarea within the same jsp and not have to send a post request to another jsp?